# Generate features from "comments" column in dataframe

Tags: python, text, dataframe, comments

I have a dataset with a column that has comments. This comments are words separated by commas.

df_pat['reason'] =

1. chest pain
2. chest pain, dyspnea
3. chest pain, hypertrophic obstructive cariomyop...
4. chest pain
5. chest pain
6. cad, rca stents
7. non-ischemic cardiomyopathy, chest pain, dyspnea

I would like to generate separated columns in the dataframe so that a column represent each word from all the set of words, and then have 1 or 0 to the rows where I initially had that word in the comment.

For example:
df_pat['chest_pain'] =
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
1

df_pat['dyspnea'] =
0
1
0
0
0
0
1

And so on...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sklearn.feature_extraction.text` has something for you! It looks like you may be trying to predict something. If so - and if you're planning to use sci-kit learn at some point, then you can bypass making a dataframe with len(set(words)) number of columns and just use `CountVectorizer`. This method will return a matrix with dimensions (rows, columns) = (number of rows in dataframe, number of unique words in entire `'reason'` column).

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame({'reason': ['chest pain', 'chest pain, dyspnea', 'chest pain, hypertrophic obstructive cariomyop', 'chest pain', 'chest pain', 'cad, rca stents', 'non-ischemic cardiomyopathy, chest pain, dyspnea']})

# turns body of text into a matrix of features
# split string on commas instead of spaces
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = lambda x: x.split(","))

# X is now a n_documents by n_distinct_words-dimensioned matrix of features
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['reason'])
```

`pandas` plays really nicely with `sklearn`.

Or, a strict `pandas` solution that should probably be vectorized, but if you don't have that much data, should work:

```
# split on the comma instead of spaces to get "chest pain" instead of "chest" and "pain"
reasons = [reason for case in df['reason'] for reason in case.split(",")]

for reason in reasons:
    for idx in df.index:
        if reason in df.loc[idx, 'reason']:
            df.loc[idx, reason] = 1
        else:
            df.loc[idx, reason] = 0
```

Comment: I see that the output X tells you where you have each word. 
The problem is, "chest pain" should be the new column, and X is showing chest and pain as separated words.
Also, in X we don't know what each column is. I guessed that (0,3) =1 meant that row 0 has 3 that represents the word chest, but that's because I compared the input and the output...

Thanks for the fast answer, I guess we can start a discussion now!

Comment: The `(0, 3)` and `(0, 9)` means that the row at index `0` contains the words indexed at `3` and `9` in `vectorizer.vocabulary_` (indexed in some list of vocabulary). Since those are the only two entries for row `0`, we know that row only has two words (features).

Comment: I updated above. You could split the strings on commas instead of spaces to get what you're looking for.

Comment: That's perfect!! The pandas option that you suggested is exactly what I needed! 
The data set has about 1000 samples so I think I'll stick with the panda option.
Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I have a quick question:

The split function doesn't work when one of the comments contains a float. 
i.e. df = pd.DataFrame({'reason': ['chest pain', 'chest pain, dyspnea 2']

Do you know a work around for this?

Comment: Try reading in the dataframe like `df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", dtype = str)`. Or you can write a script to remove all digits in the text.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to do the vectorizer version. The set of words is huge and takes a long time to do it with pandas.

Thank you for the help again!